How to make responsive on Slider Group on Vutify?
Now I am developing simple project, and facing some issues in develop.
I can't make responsive with this slider group components.
This is the source code.
<v-slide-group
      v-model="model"
      class="pa-1 !bg-black"
      center-active
      show-arrows
      mobile-breakpoint="sm"
      sm="1">
      <v-slide-group-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
        <v-card
          color="transparent"
          class="ma-4 !rounded !p-0 !m-2"
          height="290"
        >
         <content />
        </v-card>
       </v-slide-group-item>
  </v-slide-group>

I am looking for your support.
Thank you in advance.
I tried to make responsive by changing the width of v-card, it didn't work.
So I used mobile-breakpoint.
But I am not sure how to use it.

I also faced problems like you.
Instead of using slide, you can use swiper components for vue if your goal is to just make swiper.
This is the code for your requirements.
    <swiper
        ref="swiperRef"
        :slides-per-view="1"
        :space-between="20"
        @swiper="onSwiper"
        @slideChange="onSlideChange"
        :breakpoints="responsiveBreakpoints"
        class="!bg-black"
      >
        <swiper-slide
          v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="index"
          class="!bg-black"
        >
          <v-card
            color="transparent"
            class="ma-4 !rounded !p-0 !m-2 !bg-black"
            height="auto"
          >

          ....

          </v-card>
        </swiper-slide>
      </swiper>

Maybe this is useful for your project.
You can reference this url.
https://swiperjs.com/vue
